# Symfony bundles (vendor) entities - create schema, get repository problems

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

We split our logic in project into "bundles" and installing them using composer.
But we problem with DB scheme creation, because doctrine will not create scheme for entities in vendor dir.

And we have problem with getting repository, because getRepository with argument like this `Company\SomeModuleBundle\Entity\Comment` will fail with message `The class 'Company\SomeModuleBundle\Entity\Comment' was not found in the chain configured namespaces (...)`

How can we achieve creating schemes from our bundles (installed with composer) and accessing them?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you must extend the entities from your vendors in your own bundle and then you can run doctrine:schema:*

Comment: Other solution doesn't exist? Because we like to use bundles like "standalone" modules, without editing application code.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://zalas.eu/how-to-store-doctrine-entities-outside-of-a-symfony-bundle/) will be helpful. I've use only one bundle with an entity but it seems that you can give a mapping to doctrine.

Comment: Make sure you include the bundle in AppKernel.  Make sure you have doctrine:orm:auto_mapping: true.  The entities will get picked up when configured properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot add bundle into AppKernel, thats it.

Thanks @Cerad.